# Can you use Circuit lab in the Arduino forum

Tags: feature-request

The Electronics Stack Exchange has a built-in button to a free version of Circuit lab. It's not a bad little tool for creating simple circuit diagrams. I don't see a way to do that in the Arduino Stack exchange, at least not directly. I had to cheat, create a throw-away question in the EE Stack exchange, export it to a picture, then post THAT, which is quite convoluted.

If not, could Stack Exchange add that feature to the Arduino boards? It would be very useful and appropriate.

Comment: This is a duplicate... Personally I don't think the SE team will do anything until we graduate out of beta or show a real need for this. I'm not quite sure if we will get this or not... :/

Comment: You can start a question or answer in EE.SE, then draw the circuit, then copy the text insert to arduino.se, without saving the EE.SE question. Disadvantage is that you can't save the circuit. I am quite disappointed that Arduino.SE doesn't get a C/lab module (or similar.

Comment: Why is the Arduino SE in beta, and what does it take to graduate? And given that the Arduino is a hardware development platform, it seems obvious that circuit diagrams are a necessary tool.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin, the thread you linked is not really a duplicate. It was a question on "How do I create circuit diagrams on the Arduino SE." My question was specific to wanting Circuit Lab. I marked it as a feature request, and I think it has merit as such.

Comment: @DuncanC the other question is *also* a feature request. I'll still poke someone higher up though, if that would make you feel better. However, since we're still in beta, they usually don't grant us features like that unless we show an extreme need for those tools. We're in beta because, to add new SE sites, it goes through *Area 51* where users can post and vote for new proposals. When it meets certain requirements, they use a template and launch the beta site. There really isn't a *real* set of requirements as it is determined on a case-by-case basis: SE wants the site to not fail.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin In the discussion at the time I wrote my question, I was strongly adviced not to pick a specific solution (called Circuitlab) but make it a generic request for a circuit editor.